# Como pegar resposta de uma Rota com JS

Tags: javascript, laravel

A rota está configura dessa forma:

```
Route::get('database/getClubes', 'DataBase@getClubes');
```

O Controller está assim:

```
public function getClubes()
{
    return ClubesDB::getClubes();
}
```

O Model está assim:

```
public static function getClubes(){
    return ClubesDB::all();
}
```

O JS para pegar a resposta está assim:

```
this.list = jQuery.get('database/getClubes');
```

Porem não retorna nada, quando eu acesso ´database/getClubes´ diretamente aparece na pagina o resultado, porem ao usar o jQuery não retorna nada.

Comment: O que aparece no console ?

Comment: Nada, e de retorno vem uma pagina inteira, e não apenas o resultado do banco.

Comment: Na aba network normalmente mostra os requests aonde pode estar o seu

Comment: Na aba Network tem um request chamado `getClubes` exatamente com oque eu quero.

Comment: Então mestre a informação esta vindo corretamente precisa ver aonde voce esta tratando ela

Comment: Aproveitei e coloquei uma solução para seu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma que estas utilizando para popular a variavel não esta correta, tente desta forma:

```
jQuery.get('database/getClubes', function(data){
    this.list = data;
    console.log(this.list); // vai trazer no console o resultado esperado.
});
```

Comment: Estou usando desta forma o VueJS `<tr v-for="(item, index) in list"><td>{{item.clube}}</td>` e mesmo com  a `list` preenchida, a tabela continua fazia, já quando eu coloco algo dentro da `list`, funciona perfeitamente, oque pode ser ??

Comment: Ficou um pouco confuso seu comentario

Comment: Lembrando que o get precisa ser executado antes do for para quando chegar ali ele estar populado e lembrando que isto é uma pergunta diferente creio que seria mais prudente tratar em outra pergunta e marcar esta como resolvida certo ?

Comment: Vamos dizer que ele seja atualizado constantemente, qual comando posso usar do VueJS para atualizar essa tabela ??

Comment: Estranho, se eu adicionar um novo elemento em `list` ele atualiza, porem quando defino uma list inteira nova como é o caso ele não atualiza.

Comment: E se você fazer um loop no retorno e adicionar um a um na lista ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63573/discussion-between-otto-and-lucas-carezia).

Comment: Novamente sugiro que marque como resolvido como são problemas diferentes e abra um novo post com os dados do problema subsequente

Comment: Pronto, fiz outra pergunta https://goo.gl/3CZ4dx